# SQL count used in where clause

Tags: sql, count, where-clause

I'm kind of new to sql. I have got a question involving using the function count() as restriction the the where-clause in my sql.

tbl_meeting

```
ID
TIMESTAMP
CAPACITY
...
```

tbl_attendance

```
ID
NAME
...
```

(I've also got a table between because multiple attendance can go to multiple meetings)

I want to select all the meeting that are full. It should look something like this but i can figure it out.

```
select *
, count(LAM.id) as amount_attending
from tbl_meetings M
left join tbl_lnk_attendance_meeting LAM
on M.id = LAM.meeting_id
where M.capacity <> amount_attending
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this approach to find full attendance of meeting

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_meetings M
WHERE M.capacity = (SELECT COUNT(LAM.id) 
                    FROM tbl_lnk_attendance_meeting LAM 
                    WHERE M.id = LAM.meeting_id)
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I needed. Didn't know you could use a subquery in a where-clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * , count(LAM.id) as amount_attending
from tbl_meetings M
left join tbl_lnk_attendance_meeting LAM
on M.id = LAM.meeting_id 
group by LAM.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already carrying out the count function in your select statement so your where clause just needs a comparison to a number.

```
select *
, count(LAM.id) as amount_attending
from tbl_meetings M
left join tbl_lnk_attendance_meeting LAM
on M.id = LAM.meeting_id
where amount_attending = (whatever number constitutes a full meeting)
```